# Show Product category list in Woocommerce Wordpress Plugin without thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following short code to list the product categories in woocommerce Wordpress plugin

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_categories number=""]'); ?>
```

The problem is the category thumbnail that I need to get rid of. I want to hide it and doing it with CSS seems to be a big hassle. Is there anyway I can list the categories without the thumbnails appearing?

Answer (score 11):

You could use the following:

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' );
$terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

if (count($terms) > 0) {
    echo '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<a href="/term-base/' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';    
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Comment: how can i get image? i tried `$term->image` & `$term->url`

Comment: print_r($terms) to see what you get in the output. If the term has an image it should be in the array

Comment: oh i was looking for print_r function the whole day tomorrow! Thanks

Comment: Can this be modified to show grandchild categories?

Comment: @danyo i need most selling categories , how can i fetch them?

Answer (score 2):

Heres what I used for making a list of all categories by letter excluding empty letters and with category featured images!

All you need to do is style it the way you want ;)

```
<?php

/* Define which category // to list child categories array('parent'=>42) 42 is category ID */
$designers = get_terms('product_cat', array('parent'=>42));

/* If categ not empty for each designer take first letter */
if ( !empty( $designers ) && !is_wp_error( $designers ) ){    
    $term_list = [];    
    foreach ( $designers as $designer ){
        $letter = strtoupper($designer->name[0]);
        $designer_list[$letter][] = $designer;
    }
unset($designer);


    foreach ( $designer_list as $key=>$value ) {
        /* Wrap around each designer */
        echo '<div><span>' . $key . '</span><ul>';

        foreach ( $value as $designer ) {
            // Set thumbnail
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $designer->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            // get the image URL
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
            /* List designers */
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $designer ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('Products by %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $designer->name) . '">' . $designer->name . '<img src=" ' .$image.' "" alt="" /></a></li>';
        }
        /* end Wrap around designer */
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }?>
}
```